# ModuleNotFoundError in Django in Vscode

Tags: python, django

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home import views
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name='home'),
]
```

This is code in urls.py file under home app.

And now its giving following error:

```
(env) abhishek@Abhisheks-MacBook-Pro hello % /Users/abhishek/Documents/django_work/env/bin/python /Users/abhishek/Do
cuments/django_work/Hello/home/urls.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abhishek/Documents/django_work/Hello/home/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from home import views
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'home'
```

I tried this & still not working

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

Can anyone expain this? And also how to fix this.

Comment: your import is getting error fix that

Answer (score 0):

try

```
from . import views
```

because it is a import error and you are already in your home app.

I hope this helps.

Comment: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package